# convert array php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert this array content:

```
$colorList[0] = "red";
$colorList[1] = "green";
$colorList[2] = "blue";
$colorList[3] = "black";
$colorList[4] = "white";
```

into

```
array("red","green","blue","black","white")
```

how do doing that?
thanks

Comment: The two are the same.

Comment: These arrays already are equivalent.

Comment: there is no sense in doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need it.
there is no difference between these two.
What made you think you need that conversion?

Comment: yes, for now its working.
maybe I made mistake before.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your array `$colorList` does not contain other elements, then both arrays already are equivalent:

```
$a = array();
$a[0] = "red";
$a[1] = "green";
$a[2] = "blue";
$a[3] = "black";
$a[4] = "white";
$b = array("red","green","blue","black","white");

var_dump($a === $b); // bool(true)
```

They are just created in a different way.

And if you just want to get an expression that represents these arrays, you can use [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) to get an output like this:

```
array (
  0 => 'red',
  1 => 'green',
  2 => 'blue',
  3 => 'black',
  4 => 'white',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there's probably a better way to achieve what you're looking for, take a look at [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).

```
echo var_export($colorList, true); // "array('red', 'green', ...)"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need  to convert.

`$colorList` is same as `array("red","green","blue","black","white")`

Do `var_dump($colorList);` just do convince yourself.